# How Do Encryption Services Like Boxcryptor And CloudFogger Work?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, encryption, truecrypt

I am familiar with TrueCrypt and the whole volume in which I drop files and then lock everything up, but how do services like Boxcryptor and CloudFogger work? They seem to act like they have file volumes that wrap the files, but then I can move the files anywhere I want (even when logged out) like onto a hard drive and decrypt them on another machine. They even provide thumbnail view, etc which baffles me.

Are they decrypting every file automatically while I am logged into the system through my file view windows or are they using some special file volume like TrueCrypt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boxcryptor website contains a fair amount of information on [how it works](https://www.boxcryptor.com/en/technical-overview). However, if you are looking for an alternative explanation, this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovS0Q6QP7n0) (though long) is quite decent.

Comment: Hey freethebees, I really appreciate this answer. If found the how it works page a little bit ago, but was a little unclear on the client side process after reading it. The video made it infinitely easier to understand the piece I was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: @MrJman006 No problem. Sorry I didn't see this three months earlier! I imagined you would have found what you wanted by now. This might be useful to someone who comes this way in the future though.